# Skip expression bodied property in debugger

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Is there analog of `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute available for expression-bodied properties in C# ?

For example I want to skip over the code

```
public Byte ByteArray => Builder.CreateArray();
```

`[DebuggerStepThrough]` can not be applied to properties. Does C# team provide any other solution in C# 6.0 ?

Comment: Did you try doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DebuggerStepThrough` isn't valid for expression bodied properties as this:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public Byte ByteArray => Builder.CreateArray();
```

Doesn't compile. This however does:

```
public Byte ByteArray
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    get
    {
        return Builder.CreateArray();
    }
}
```

There are other debugger attributes like `DebuggerHidden` and `DebuggerNonUserCode`, but they don't disable step-through.

You can disable it for all properties in the debugging options, but there's no way IMO to configure it only for expression-bodied properties.

Comment: @Ask only these properties?

Comment: @Ask Unless you can attach the attribute to the whole class, the workaround is exactly as i3arnon showed, don't use the expression bodied syntax.

Comment: @Ask And I think i3arnon's answer is pretty clear to your clarification. The answer is "No, they did not, you must use the pre 6.0 syntax of creating a property".

Answer (score 1):

C# 9.0: still no luck. An expression body can be used however:

```
public Byte ByteArray
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    get => Builder.CreateArray();
}
```

or the same code as one-liner:

```
public Byte ByteArray {[DebuggerStepThrough] get => Builder.CreateArray();}
```