# method Attribute on C# expression-bodied member

Tags: c#, syntax, properties, attributes, c#-6.0

Is there any way to specify an `AttributeTargets.Method` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute?view=netframework-4.7) on an [expression-bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) in C# 6? Consider the following read-only property:

```
public bool IsLast { [DebuggerStepThrough] get { return _next == null; } }
```

The abbreviated synax would be:

```
public bool IsLast => _next == null;
```

But there appears to be nowhere to put the method attribute. None of the following work:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public bool IsLast => _next == null;      // decorates property, not method

public bool IsLast => [DebuggerStepThrough] _next == null;    // error

public bool IsLast [DebuggerStepThrough] => _next == null;    // error
```

---

<sub>[Edit:] Suggesting that this is not a duplicate of ['Skip expression bodied property in debugger'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035317/skip-expression-bodied-property-in-debugger) since this question asks about *any* method-suitable attribute in general, rather than just the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute--which is only given as an example here--in particular.</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip expression bodied property in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035317/skip-expression-bodied-property-in-debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: The following syntax works but it is not quite as compact as the (non-working) attempts shown in the question.

```
public bool IsLast { [DebuggerStepThrough] get => _next == null;  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply an `AttributeTargets.Method` attribute to an expression-bodied *method*, but not to an expression-bodied *property*.